# Is there a way to display BOX DRAWINGS symbols in intelij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, console, symbols

I use StringBuilder to draw a state of gamefield in TicTacToe.
And if I use symbols like "┯" or "━", IDEA returns "?" in console output.
Is there any way to display them properly?

Things I had already tried:

1. Edit custom VM properties "-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8"
2. Editor -> Color Scheme  -> Console Font. Tried different fonts.

Comment: Please try to add "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" to VM options as well.

Comment: Yup, already tried with -Dconsole. They're still in vm options for now.

Comment: Am I got you right that now you have two options set "-Dfile.encoding" and "-Dconsole"? Have you restarted IDE?